# I have a testng class inside testng method , invoking another method via reflection it fails to log in testng report

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider

Code Sample :

Test1 class would be a parent class which would be responsible to execute Test2 class method

import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class Test1 {

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Class test2 = Test2.class;
    Method method = null;
    Object obj = null;
    try {
        method = test2.getMethod("test", String.class);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    method.setAccessible(true);

    try {
        obj = method.invoke(test2.newInstance(), "0");

    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException | InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Test2.class code :

import org.testng.Assert;

public class Test2 {

```
public void test(String obj){

    Assert.assertEquals(obj, "1");
}
```

}
Here as per this example , assertion should fail , but testng report states as passed
So how do i link assertion failure to the testng report

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by calling the test from another class?  Why not use xml or testng programmatic invocation?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to isolate the handler of InvocationTargetException in a single catch block and check the result using getCause(). Here is what I tried;

```
try {
    Object obj = method.invoke(test2obj, "0");
} catch( InvocationTargetException e){
    Throwable e1 = e.getCause();
    System.out.println("Method invocation failed... due to " + e1); 
} catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And I got this message;

```
Method invocation failed... due to org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[0]> but was:<[1]>
```